# Gsutil notification stopchannel giving failure

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I followed this tutorial ([Object Change Notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification)), it worked in watching step.
But I can not stop watching with response:

```
$ gsutil notification stopchannel my_channel-id my_resource-id
Removing channel my_channel-id with resource identifier my_resource-id
Failure: initializer for ctype 'char *' must be a str or list or tuple, not unicode.
```

**gsutil version: 4.6**

---

**EDIT: problem fixed**

I debug with -DD option

```
$ gsutil -DD notification stopchannel my_channel-id my_resource-id
```

It printed exception from my virtualenv so I deactivate virtualenv and run stopchannel again.

It worked. ^^